# ¿Cómo justificar elementos usando flex?

Tags: css

Tengo el siguiente código de una barra de búsqueda, al momento de posicionar los elementos, el `input` que funciona como **busqueda** aparece más grande que los demás, posicionándose arriba y expandiéndose conforme se escribe.

#### ¿Cómo podría justificar el elemento búsqueda para que solo ocupe el espacio disponible después de los `select`?

Esto sin afectar el espacio del *texto* en los `select` y el boton de buscar.

```css
.card {
 width:75%;
 height:35px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-left: 10px;
 background-color:#fafafa;
 background-position: 8px 8px; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 transition: 0.3s;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.card-options{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
   
input#busqueda{
 border: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 margin: 0px;
 height: 35px;
 width: 40%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: transparent;    
 outline-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 2px;
 font-size: 17px;  
}
select.mdl-textfield__input{
 margin-top:4px;
 display: inline-block;
 width:120px;
 outline-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
 <div class="card-options">
  <select id="grupos" class="mdl-textfield__input">
   <option value="Grupo" name="grupo">Grupo</option>
  </select>
  <select id="marcas" class="mdl-textfield__input">
   <option value="Marca"  name="marca">Marca</option>
  </select>        
  <input id="busqueda" placeholder="Escriba su busqueda" type="text" name="busqueda"/>
  <input id="buscar" type="submit" style="float:right;" value="Buscar" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que buscar justificar entre los elementos de tal manera que la barra de búsqueda siempre ocupe el resto del área que no ocupan los select y el botón.

Si entendi bien, esto lo puedes lograr usando calc, ya que puedes darle una medida al boton de digamos 70px, más los 120px de cada boton, eso suma = 310px, por lo que podrías asignar un width al input de búsqueda así: `width: calc(100% - 310px);` con esto solo debes flotar todos los elementos.

Ahora, sí lo quieres lograr con flexbox, es mucho más fácil, puedes por ejemplo añadir como te recomendaron lo siguiente al padre contenedor del problema:

```
.card-options{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

A todos los elementos directos hijos de `card-options`le ponemos un limite de crecimiento en flex así:

```
.card-options > *{  flex-grow: 1;  }
```

Y al elemento que va a ocupar más porcentaje de la barra le añadimos, el limite lo más alto que creamos, por ejemplo:

```
.card-options #busqueda{  flex-grow: 97;  }
```

Mira por ejemplo aquí:

```css
.card {
 width:75%;
 height:35px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-left: 10px;
 background-color:#fafafa;
 background-position: 8px 8px; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 transition: 0.3s;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.card-options{
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.card-options *{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
   
input#busqueda{
  min-width: 10em; /*Esto puede estar en un mediaquerie que afecte a smartphone*/
  flex-grow: 50;
 border: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 margin: 0px;
 height: 35px;
 width: 40%;
 /*position: absolute;borrar*/
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: transparent;    
 outline-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 2px;
 font-size: 17px;  
}
select.mdl-textfield__input{
 margin-top:4px;
 display: inline-block;
 width:120px;
 outline-color: transparent;
}

#buscar{
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
 <div class="card-options">
  <select id="grupos" class="mdl-textfield__input">
   <option value="Grupo" name="grupo">Grupo</option>
  </select>
  <select id="marcas" class="mdl-textfield__input">
   <option value="Marca"  name="marca">Marca</option>
  </select>        
  <input id="busqueda" placeholder="Escriba su busqueda" type="text" name="busqueda"/>
  <input id="buscar" type="submit" value="Buscar" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Como ves de esa manera, le indicamos que mientras que los otros elementos no van a crecer para ocupar mucho, le decimos que le otro input si que seguira creciendo.

Answer (score 2):

NO entendí mucho tu pregunta, pero hablando de flex-box....

```
.card-options{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

EL .card ponlo en 100%.

**justify-content: space-between** te ajustará el contenido de acuerdo al contenedor en proporciones iguales

**align-items: center;** te alineará todo el contenido verticalmente. Puedes eliminar todos los inline-block porque flex-box se encarga de hacer el trabajo.

Elimina el  style="float:right;

Comment: No ha funcionado, el input aun queda encimado del boton de buscar

Comment: Coloca el código en codepen para ayudarte.